# how to make selected links to become bold

Tags: php

I'm learning php following some tutorials
but the codes are not working as directed by the tutorials.
I want to make a selected page to become bold. these are the codes.

```
<?php

    $subject_set = get_all_subjects();

    while($subject = mysqli_fetch_array($subject_set)) {
        echo "<li";
        if ($subject["id"] == $sel_subj) {
            echo "class=\"selected\"";
        }
        echo "><a href=\"content.php?subj=" . urlencode
        ($subject["id"]) . "\">{$subject["menu_name"]}</a></li>";
        $page_set = get_all_pages_for_subject($subject["id"]);
        echo "<ul class=\pages\">";
        while($page = mysqli_fetch_array($page_set)) {
            echo "<li><a href=\"content.php?page=" . urlencode
            ($page["id"]) . "\">{$page["menu_name"]}</a>
            </li>";
            } 
        echo "</ul>";

    }

?>
```

Comment: You'd actually need a css file(or inline-style, whatever strikes your fancy) to give the class `selected` a style to work with. Currently it doesn't do anything, as this stands.

Comment: It would be a good idea to ask about/show the rendered html - not the php code used to generate it.

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML document you need this

```
<head>
   <style>
      li.selected{
        font-weight: bold;
      }
   </style>
</head>
```

Currently you are setting the selected list item to have a class of "selected" but your not actually assigning the css class "selected" from the limited example you provided.

You can learn more here:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp